# How to display a jpanel thats been passed as an argument in netbeans?

Tags: java, netbeans, jframe, jpanel

I have used the Netbeans GUI Designer to come up with a JFrame and I wish to pass in two `JPanel`s to the 2 dummy `JPanel`s already placed inside the JFrame using the Netbeans GUI Designer.

However, the code below doesn't work and the `JFrame` comes up blank. Why is that so?

```
 public Summary_Page(JPanel jp1,JPanel jp2) {

    initComponents();
    this.jp1=jp1;
    this.jp2=jp2;
    this.setVisible(true);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this method is inside the class which extends JFrame, then just add the following line inside the Summary_Page() method:

```
this.add(panel);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add panel to the parent component. If your class extends `JFrame` for example, use

```
this.getContentPane().add(panel);
```

(there is no need to set it `visible`). `JFrame` - is a window that has header and buttons(exit, minimize) but you want to add components in white rectangle so you getting `content pane` at first. If you have another parent component instead of `JFrame` you can add component this way:

```
this.add(panel);
```

Then if you want to add more then one component you need to use one of [Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html).